# Uncaught TypeError: v.setCanvasSize is not a function

Tags: javascript, oop

I am a fairly beginner programmer, so excuse me if the solution to this one is fairly simple (Although I have looked hard into finding an already-posted solution). I am debugging some code and I get this error message when running the program:

"Uncaught TypeError: v.setCanvasSize is not a function (in File1.js line 7)"

I assumed it was an issue with not yet having created the setCanvasSize function yet before doing stuff to it. So I created the timeout, but that doesn't seem to help either.

## File1.js

```
v = new V3(v3);

setTimeout
(
        function()
        {
        v.setCanvasSize
           ({
            width:  500,
            height: 300
            }, 
            function(result, err) 
            {
            console.log(result);
            }
           );
        }, 

1000
);
```

## File2.js

```
V3 = typeof V3 === "undefined" ? {} : V3;

V3.File2 = function()
{
    this.setCanvasSize = function(){};
};
```